# How to make a copy of vector of shared_ptrs?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, shared-ptr

There is `vector` of `shared_ptr` to base class.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = 0 {}
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
};

struct Derived2 : Base
{
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v;
v.push_back(std::make_shared<Base>(Derived1()));
v.push_back(std::make_shared<Base>(Derived2()));
```

How can I make a copy of the `vector`?
Pointers of the copy must point to new objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "[p]ointers of the copy must point to new objects"? Do you mean that the new vector should create *copies* of the object pointed to by `v`? Then what's the use of `std::shared_ptr`? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? *Why* do you want to make copies of the objects?

Comment: Copying a `shared_ptr` essentially just increases the reference count. You can trivially copy your vector by simply assigning it to another vector.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want deep copy of shared_ptr collection?

I will only refer to the following article.

[Deep copy constructor with std::vector of smart pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716018/deep-copy-constructor-with-stdvector-of-smart-pointers)

---

And this is the code I just wrote.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
    string _name;

public:
    virtual shared_ptr<Parent> clone() const = 0;
    Parent(const string& name) { _name = name; }
    string getName() { return _name; }
    void setName(const string& name) { _name = name; }
};

class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(const string& name) : Parent(name) {}
    virtual shared_ptr<Parent> clone() const { return make_shared<Child>(*this); }
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Parent>> origins =
    {
        shared_ptr<Parent>(new Child("ant")),
        shared_ptr<Parent>(new Child("bee")),
        shared_ptr<Parent>(new Child("cat")),
    };

    vector<shared_ptr<Parent>> clones;

    // copy origins to clones
    transform(
        origins.begin(),
        origins.end(),
        back_inserter(clones),
        [](const shared_ptr<Parent>& ptr) -> shared_ptr<Parent> { return ptr->clone(); }
    );

    // modify values of origins
    for (const auto& origin : origins) { origin->setName(origin->getName() + "!"); }

    // print origins (modified)
    cout << "<origins>" << endl;
    for (const auto& origin : origins) { cout << origin->getName() << endl; }

    // print clones (not modified)
    cout << "<clones>" << endl;
    for (const auto& clone : clones) { cout << clone->getName() << endl; }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a link but please note that link only answers are considered bad answers as if the link breaks your answer doesn't contain anything helpful.  I've closed the question as a duplicate and one you get 15+ rep you will be able to flag it as a duplicate 
 yourself.

Comment: Thanks to you, I will learn rules.

Answer (score 3):

You should add a pure `virtual` member function like `clone` to `Base`.  Implement it in your derived `class`es, then do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> copy(std::shared_ptr<Base> const &input) {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> ret;
    ret.reserve(input.size());
    for(auto const &p: input) {
        ret.push_back(p->clone());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

That being said, this is a bad idea.  You're breaking semantics such as direct assignment of `vector`s and copy constructors, since they won't do what users will expect (assuming you actually need to actually make a new instance of each object).

Comment: I'd prefer *"a (possibly pure) virtual"*; enforcing purity might break potentially desired existence of bare `Base`s...

Answer (score 0):

Just copy it.

```
auto v2 = v;
```

The container holds shared pointers so they will be fine after a copy and still point to the same objects while keeping them alive. There's no problem here.

Comment: Perhaps OP edited, but they've specified they want new objects, not pointers to the same objects.

Comment: I need to get pointers to copies of origin vector elements

Comment: So you just want a copy of each element in the vector, right?